# Django API how validation message back to user

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, json

I'm using TastyPie to register a new user. I would like to display any validation messages back to the user in an alert box. I have noticed that TastyPie gives me the following back: `responseJSON` and `responseText`.

```
responseJSON Object { accounts/create={...}}

accounts/create
    Object { email=[1], password2=[1]}

responseText
    "{"accounts/create": {"email": ["This field is required."], "password2": ["This field is required."]}}"
```

How do I show the validation back to the user and parse this correctly? Does TastyPie have any inbuilt functions to parse errors?

This is what I have so far on error which runs but I don't get any error message:

```
 error: function(errorThrown){
                      data = JSON.parse(errorThrown.responseText);
                      alert(data.error)
                      console.log(errorThrown);
                  }
              });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error seems to be on the jQuery side. The *error* key points to a function defined differently (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

> error 
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
>   A function to be called if the request fails. The
>   function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that
>   occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible
>   values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
>   "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
>   receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found"
>   or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can
>   accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.
>   Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

So your JS code ought to be,

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ...
},
```

But actually, when you return the data from django, that is a **success**. "Error" in jQuery means a *communication error*, not a *semantic error*.

If you use just

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("An error!")
},
```

you'll probably see that it does not get called (you need to return a 400/500 error code from django to have it be called).

So what you can do is differentiate between what you *successfully* return in case of "true" success, and what you *successfully* return in case of a server side failure: something like,

```
# and/or answer.data['errorMessage'] = "Error type II"
answer.data['success'] = False
return answer
```

and then in jQuery:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //  instead of checking for success, you can check the content of
    //  the "accounts/create" key
    // if (!data.success) {

    // I assume that this key won't be present in case of error.
    if (data["accounts/create"]) {

        alert("Errors will now be displayed")
        // ...here, the same code in Corinne Kubler's answer; or you
        // can make it more jQueryish with e.g. .each()
        return;
    }
    alert("Everything OK, proceeding")
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
    var jsonString = '{"accounts/create": {"email": ["This field is required."], "password2": ["This field is required."]}}';
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var inputsInError = (data["accounts/create"]);
    for (var key in inputsInError) {
       if (inputsInError.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           alert(key + " -> " + inputsInError[key]);
       }
     }
```

See jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q7Tuh/